# Get all method names with annotation where abc() method was called inside it

Tags: java, spring, performance, logic, scanning

I have a method with custom annotations

Ex:

```
@names("value1","value2") 
Public static void temp() {
    // few lines of code
    ABC("value1") ;
}
```

I want to know whether the first parameter passed in ABC() method should match with any one of the @names annotation values

How can I compare this in each file and for every method dynamically

I tried to get all method names and it's annotations but I am not able to check for ABC() method whether ABC() method called inside the methods or not

Note:: I am using only java

Thanks

Comment: This is only possible by using a compiler-dependent API, to access the AST. In case of `javac`, see [jdk.compiler](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/jdk.compiler/module-summary.html), in case of ecj (Eclipse’s compiler), you can [start here](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/)